# Show that $\det(A-\lambda B)$ is a nonconstant polynomial if $B$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be arbitrary complex square matrices. If $B$ is invertible, show that $$p(\lambda)=\det(A-\lambda B)$$ is a nonconstant polynomial in $\lambda$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $B$ is invertible, the leading term is ${\sf det}(B)(-\lambda)^n$ which is nonzero.

Comment: is there a way to prove that if $A$ and $B$ are hermitian, then roots of that polynomial will be eigenvalues of $B^{-1}A$

Comment: It took me a minute of thought to believe the leading coefficient is just $\pm\operatorname{det}(B)$. For the sake of students who have to write a proof of such a thing, is there a clean way to write out *why* this is true?

Comment: @MikePierce Sure. To put it in one sentence, when you expand the determinant as a sum of products, only one of them has a coefficient of degree $n$ - the product of the diagonal terms. Every other product will have degree at most $n-1$.